# Updating Info-path 2010 form in SharePoint 2010 Issue

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I am running into a weird problem. I have three SharePoint list and was successful in editing the interface using Infopath from the list>> Customize Form option. But the problem raised for one particular list.

Initially, I changed the look n feel of it using InfoPath and published it but now when i am trying to update any further changes, its not happening.

When i am opening the form in InfoPath its showing all the updated changes but whenever i am publishing it and then trying to open a new item or update an existing item, the previous form is showing up instead of the updated one!

Comment: to clarify the form the opens when you click "Customize Form" is different than the form you get when creating a new item?

Answer (score -1):

You need to deploy the updated InfoPath form in Central Admin. Goto Central Admin > General Application Settings > Upload Form Template and upload your published InfoPath form. Then, as long as the list is associated with the form, when you create a new item, you will see the new InfoPath form. Sadly, this won' work for existing items in the list, only new ones.

Good luck!